# How can I reduce timing to solve this equation?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

I am tring to solve equation $$\frac{2 \log (x y+2021)}{\log
   (2)}+4^{x+1}=2^{x y+2022}+\frac{2
   \log (2 x+1)}{\log (2)},$$
where $x$, $y$ are integer numbers.
I tried

```
Reduce[4^(x + 1) + 2 Log[2, x y + 2021] == 
  2^(x y + 2022) + 2 Log[2, 2 x + 1], {x, y}, Integers]
```

My computer runs too long. How can I reduce timing to solve this equation?

Comment: This is math, not Mathematica. I vote to close the question.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, I solved it by hand. But, I want to solve it by Mathematica.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, neither `Reduce` or `Solve` seem to be able to provide any solutions. However, if we fix `x` to integer values, `FindInstance` is able to give us at least *a* solution. For the first couple of integers we get

```
{x -> 1, y -> -2018}
{x -> 2, y -> -1008}
{x -> 3, y -> -2014/3}
{x -> 4, y -> -503}
{x -> 5, y -> -402}
{x -> 6, y -> -1004/3}
{x -> 7, y -> -2006/7}
```

There is a pattern here, and one can check that the following is always solution to your equation

```
y[x_] := -2020/x + 2
```

This can be checked analytically

```
{4^(x + 1) + 2 Log[2, x y + 2021],
  2^(x y + 2022) + 2 Log[2, 2 x + 1]} /. y -> y[x] // Simplify

(*
   {4^(1 + x) + (2 Log[1 + 2 x])/Log[2], 
    4^(1 + x) + (2 Log[1 + 2 x])/Log[2]}
*)
```

so this also holds for real values of `x`.

For `y` to be an integer, `x` needs to be a divisor of `2020`, so we get the following set of integer solutions

```
{{x -> -2020, y -> 3}, {x -> -1010, y -> 4}, {x -> -505, 
  y -> 6}, {x -> -404, y -> 7}, {x -> -202, y -> 12}, {x -> -101, 
  y -> 22}, {x -> -20, y -> 103}, {x -> -10, y -> 204}, {x -> -5, 
  y -> 406}, {x -> -4, y -> 507}, {x -> -2, y -> 1012}, {x -> -1, 
  y -> 2022}, {x -> 1, y -> -2018}, {x -> 2, y -> -1008}, {x -> 4, 
  y -> -503}, {x -> 5, y -> -402}, {x -> 10, y -> -200}, {x -> 20, 
  y -> -99}, {x -> 101, y -> -18}, {x -> 202, y -> -8}, {x -> 404, 
  y -> -3}, {x -> 505, y -> -2}, {x -> 1010, y -> 0}, {x -> 2020, 
  y -> 1}}
```

However, there may be solutions outside of this set.

**Edit**

Your equation can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
2^{2x+1}-2^{xy+2021} = \log_2{\left(\frac{2x+1}{xy+2021}\right)}
\end{equation}

The solution found above is just the condition for both sides to vanish, i.e.

\begin{equation}
2x+1=xy+2021,
\end{equation}

which is a much nicer derivation.

Comment: It should be noticed that `4^(x + 1)- 2^(x y + 2022)` is a rational number assuming `x` and `y` integer. This implies a certain condition for the arguments of the logarithms. BTW, all the solutions found with Maple satisfy both `4^(x + 1)== 2^(x y + 2022)`  and `2 Log[2, x y + 2021] == 
 2 Log[2, 2 x + 1]`.

Comment: Up to traditional math, `{x -> -20, y -> 103}` is not a solution in view of `FunctionDomain[4^(x + 1) + 2 Log[2, x y + 2021], {x, y}, Reals]` which produces `x y > -2021`. The true  solutions are found by `Reduce[4^(x + 1) == 2^(x y + 2022) && 
  Log[2, x y + 2021] == Log[2, 2 x + 1], {x, y}, Integers]`.

Comment: I don't understand your point. At ```{x -> -20, y -> 103} ``` both sides of the original equation become complex, but we have equality nonetheless, so it is a valid integer solution.

Comment: Hausdorff, up to traditional math, integer solutions have to belong to the domains of the functions which are defined by the LHS and RHS over the reals and `Reduce[Log[2, x y + 2021] == Log[2, 2 x + 1], {x, y}, Integers]` takes it into account. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.